# Arrow vector notation

Tags: vector

I'm using `\overrightarrow`to denote vectors because I didn't like the output `\vec` was giving in some cases. The problem is I don't like `\overrightarrow` either. I'm getting something that kinda get mixed up with the actual letter it's above.
`\overrightarrow{\gamma}` gives me this

[image]

I was hoping to get something kinda more like this

[image]

How do I get this? I don't know if it's relevant, but I'm using some standard packages for math writings along with some others.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it! I've learned the type of arrow I wanted is an old style of arrow. To get this old style you just need to include `\usepackage{old-arrows}` to the code and you get exactly the second image writing `\overrightarrow{\gamma}`.

Comment: or `\usepackage[a]{esvect}` ...

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,esvect}
\begin{document}
        
$\vv{\gamma}(t)$

\end{document}
```

[image]